# xpages: data binding to fields is not updated when dynamically changing the datasource

Tags: xpages

Up to now I have been able to solve all XPages related problems by searching the net, but this one keeps driving me crazy and I could really use some help:

On my XPage I have a panel with a dynamic datasource (documentid and action are computed (values from `sessionScope`)). In this panel I have multiple edit boxes that are bound to the datasource via "simple binding". Outside of the panel I have a combo box where the user can choose a document to show and a button to create a new document. When the combo box value changes, I put documentid and action to `sessionScope` and perform a partial update of the panel. Everything works fine and the documents are shown the right way. When I press the button to create a new document (documentid="",action="newDocument") I get a new document and the edit boxes in the panel are empty, just the way it should be.

However, if I pick an existing document from the combo box after creating a new one, the edit boxes are not updated but stay the same as in the document I just created. I figured out that the partial refresh worked for the datasource (documentid is correct) but it seems that the data binding didn't work, meaning that the values from the document are not written to the edit boxes. Afterwards, if I pick another document from the combo box or perform another partial refresh, the data binding suddenly works again.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Why do I need 2 partial refreshes here?

What i tried to solve this problem but didn't work:

1. Changing scope of datasource to request
2. Performing full update instead of just a partial update of the panel
3. Setting `ignorerequestparameter` to `true`
4. All possible settings of `computewithform`

I know I could manually write the data from the document to the edit boxes, but I think it should be possible to solve this without a workaround.

Comment: look at order of components and check your code against JSF lifecycle - what and when is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by trying lots of possible parameter combinations for the datasource as well as the refresh options i found the solution:

when performing the partial refresh of the panel, i have to set **"Process data without validation"** to true in the **"Server Options"**. i can't explain why it works now, especially as i don't even use any validation of the fields. yet, it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is a SSJS port of some Java code that I use to reset the local field values for fields bound to beans, when changing bean values server side. Without doing this, the UI fields show the "old" values.

The SSJS isn't tested, so there might be typos. Hopefully you will figure it out if it you get errors.

```
function resetComponentAndChildren( component ) {
    if( component instanceof javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder ) {
        // Reset value bindings on component
        var valueHolder = component;
        valueHolder.setSubmittedValue( null );
        valueHolder.setValue( null );
        valueHolder.setLocalValueSet( false );
        valueHolder.setValid( true );
    }

    var children = component.getChildren();
    for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i++ ) {       
        resetComponentAndChildren( children[i] );
    }
}

function resetRefreshTargetAndChildren(){
    var refreshId = param.get( "$$ajaxid" ).replaceFirst( "^view:", "" );
    var refreshTarget = view.findComponent( refreshId );
    resetComponentAndChildren( refreshTarget );
}
```

**resetRefreshTargetAndChildren** is used to reset fields for the area that's partially refreshed. If your combobox event results in refreshing the area that has all the document fields, it should fit your needs (if your issue is the same that I had with beans). Call it in the onChange event for the combo box.

Comment: luckily i just managed to solve the problem by coincidence. yet, your approach is another workaround that would solve it too - thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what you want to do is possible...  though I'd need to see your code to mock something up to play with it.  Certainly you will want to have ignoreRequestParams set.. I typically try to avoid using computeWithForm at all costs.

While you should be able to get this to work via data binding, I'm more apt typically to not bind the edit fields for something like this to a document data source.  I think I'd leave them unbound and then use SSJS to populate the values and then save the values.  I don't think of that as a "workaround" or a "hack" - that's just another valid way to do it in my opinion.

Comment: you are right: it's not a hack, but i considered it a workaround because simple data binding offers a lot of features "out-of-the-box" that i would have to code when populating and saving the fields manually. btw: why are you trying to avoid computewithform at all costs?

Comment: computeWithForm IMO is bad for several reasons.  Biggest is it separates/hides your logic. Now you are coding on the form as well. Gets harder to maintain. Best to keep logic in as few places as possible. Also what if there was an error when the form computes? hard to deal with.  Also I think there's a performance hit.  I'm sure it's slower then staying inside xpages and sticking with SSJS.